# CF user-provided-service Route Service is limiting the response body of the API

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am facing this issue where I create a user-provided-service and bind-route-service to my application.

This Spring-boot application does the following to each request:

1. List item
2. Intercepts an incoming request
3. Logs information about that incoming request
4. Transforms the incoming request to an outgoing request
5. Logs information about that outgoing request
6. Forwards the request to the targeted API using RestOperations.exchange

The problem that I face is, when I am doing a get request where I am supposed to get close to 100 entries in the response I get an empty body and a 200 OK response.
This same call to application works fine when I do the request with $top value of less than equal to 4.
The same call to my application works fine and returns me 100 entries in response body when I don’t bind my service to the application.

While logging the incoming requests and outgoing requests, I have observed that only thing my route-service-application is doing is removing the X-CF-Forwarded-Url that is added by Gorouter.
I have hit a dead-end with this, any help/direction in this regards will be greatly appreciated.

**Exception logs:**

```
Message:
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
Stacktrace:
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes
OutputBuffer.java:393
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append
ByteChunk.java:344
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes
OutputBuffer.java:418
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write
OutputBuffer.java:406
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write
CoyoteOutputStream.java:97
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write
CoyoteOutputStream.java:90
org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy
StreamUtils.java:92
org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal
ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.java:65
org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal
ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.java:37
org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write
AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:195
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters
AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:238
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue
HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:183
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue
HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle
ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod
RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal
RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle
AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch
DispatcherServlet.java:959
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService
DispatcherServlet.java:893
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest
FrameworkServlet.java:968
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet
FrameworkServlet.java:859
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service
HttpServlet.java:622
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service
FrameworkServlet.java:844
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service
HttpServlet.java:729
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:292
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:207
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter
WsFilter.java:52
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:240
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:207
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal
EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:237
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter
OncePerRequestFilter.java:107
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:240
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:207
org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal
WebRequestTraceFilter.java:112
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter
OncePerRequestFilter.java:107
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:240
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:207
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal
RequestContextFilter.java:99
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter
OncePerRequestFilter.java:107
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:240
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:207
org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal
HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter
OncePerRequestFilter.java:107
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:240
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:207
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal
HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter
OncePerRequestFilter.java:107
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:240
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:207
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal
CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter
OncePerRequestFilter.java:107
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:240
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:207
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal
MetricsFilter.java:103
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter
OncePerRequestFilter.java:107
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:240
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
ApplicationFilterChain.java:207
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke
StandardWrapperValve.java:212
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke
StandardContextValve.java:106
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke
AuthenticatorBase.java:502
org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke
RemoteIpValve.java:676
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke
StandardHostValve.java:141
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke
ErrorReportValve.java:79
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke
StandardEngineValve.java:88
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service
CoyoteAdapter.java:522
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process
AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process
AbstractProtocol.java:672
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun
NioEndpoint.java:1500
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run
NioEndpoint.java:1456
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run
TaskThread.java:61
java.lang.Thread.run
Thread.java:748
```

Comment: Can you look at the request and response on your target application?  When going through the route service, does the target app receive the request that you expect?  Does it return the expected result?  Before you look too much at the route service, make sure that what's being sent to the target app is 100% correct and that it's returning the correct result.  If the values in and out of the target app are correct, then you can narrow your focus to the route service.  If you can be resonably sure the issue is in the route service, then you can step through with a debugger to see what happens.

Comment: @DanielMikusa I did verify from my targeted application and I am receiving the expected request and sending the expected response when I bind/unbind my route service.

Comment: I tried using the sample spring-boot application provided with the CF documentation in Route Service, that too giving the same problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how to replicate?  Provide the exact steps that you're doing so that someone else can reproduce the error.  I tried https://github.com/nebhale/route-service-example using the instructions from the README, and it worked fine for me.  I was able to download a 100M file just fine with this route service bound to my app.

Comment: I used the same github example. The response is coming fine till the route-service its only after it is being sent to client that body is getting lost.
I have logged the exception, and edited the question with stacktrace.

Comment: `java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer` would imply there's some sort of network issue.  It looks like Tomcat is trying to write the data back, but can't.  Do you see any corresponding errors in your GoRouter logs?  Also, how long is the connection active?  GoRouter does have timeouts, but they're usually quite large like 900s.

Comment: @DanielMikusa thanks for your time on this. Was able to narrow down the issue to the http connection header, which was close, and the chunked transfer was not getting completed. So a keep-alive was required for transfer of chunks to complete. By default the header was set to close.